# Chart doesn't render in angular 2 app

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am using ng2-charts (https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts). I am trying to create a pie chart but when I load the app there is no chart showed. I checked all my components twice for any errors but couldn't find any, it also compiles correctly. I might be doing some silly mistakes but don't know what.

markup

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>ChartJS - Pie Chart</title>
  <link href="style.css" ref="stylesheet"></link>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas baseChart
        [data]="chartData"
        [labels]="chartLabels"
        [options]="chartOptions"
        [chartType]="chartType">
    </canvas>
</body>
```

component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'pie-chart',
  templateUrl: './pie-chart.html'
})
export class PieChartDemoComponent {
  public pieChartLabels:string[] = ['Download Sales', 'In-Store Sales', 'Mail Sales'];
  public pieChartData:number[] = [300, 500, 100];
  public pieChartType:string = 'pie';
```

Can someone tell me what I am missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems from your markup, it might be an issue with the warping of canvas element. Generally it is required to wrap the `canvas` element with a `div` element *(or a element that has the style `display: block` set)*, like so :

```
<div class="chart-container">
    <canvas baseChart
            [data]="chartData"
            [labels]="chartLabels"
            [options]="chartOptions"
            [chartType]="chartType">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: Yes, that did it. Dont know how I miss that. Thanks so much!